# NSArray of UIBarButtonItem Tag (i.e. NSInteger)

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uibarbuttonitem, nsnumber, nsinteger

Is it true that you can't have an NSMutableArray of NSIntegers? When I try to add the values to the array and then print them out they're huge numbers (when if I print out the tag to NSLog they're 0,1,2,3 etc.).

I'm trying to create an array of my UITabBarItem's tags so I can save the order and retrieve it later. Am I forced to do some conversion to an NSNumber to store into the array and then convert back on launch to get the integer value?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, you need to "box" them inside of NSNumbers before adding them to an NSMutableArray, you can do `[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:item.tag]];`